# ORA-01830 Error occuring when selecting subpartition - works on tables with none

Tags: sql, oracle

We use a partition management package that automatically creates and drops partitions with a naming format of YYYY_MM_DD.

At the moment the process has only been used with tables with 1 partition level, and we now need to add sub partitions to some tables.

The commands we use to drop the tables etc all work as normal on the new sub partitioned table (e.g. ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION "YYYY_MM_DD"), however the cursor we use to calculate those that need to be dropped causes a ORA-01830 error.

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
and TO_DATE(PARTITION_NAME, 'YYYY_MM_DD') < SYSDATE;
```

When 'TABLE_NAME' is a normal partitioned table the command works correctly, yet when it is the sub partitioned table it errors ORA-01830.

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME, TO_DATE(PARTITION_NAME, 'YYYY_MM_DD')
FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

The above works - it just seems to be when using it in the where clause we are having issues.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the full text of the error message to the question. Also, some examples of your partition names would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a query like

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME
  FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
   and TO_DATE(PARTITION_NAME, 'YYYY_MM_DD') < SYSDATE;
```

Oracle is free to evaluate predicates in any order it chooses.  `user_tab_partitions` is a view that joins a number of different objects (you could trace it back to a bunch of x$ objects and in-memory structures if you were so inclined).  If there is one row in any of those objects where the `partition_name` isn't a valid date, even if it's not related to this particular table, this statement might fail.  If you happen to get lucky and your query plan involves applying the `table_name` predicate to filter out all the data that wouldn't convert correctly before applying the `to_date` predicate, the query would work.  If you happen to get unlucky, Oracle tries to apply the `to_date` predicate to a row on which the conversion throws an error before evaluating the `table_name` predicate.  Since query plans may change over time, it is possible that the query that works now will continue to work until one day it fails (and vice versa, the query that is currently failing might suddenly start working tomorrow or next week or next year).  You may also get failures when the data in the underlying objects changes which is what I suspect happened here when you added subpartitions.

One option to resolve this is to create your own function that attempts to do the string to date conversion and swallows the error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_to_date( p_str IN VARCHAR2, 
                                       p_mask IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
  l_dt date;
BEGIN
  l_dt := to_date( p_str, p_mask );
  return l_dt;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RETURN null;
END;
```

In real code, you'd probably want to catch the actual exception rather than using a `when others`.  But that would allow you to do something like

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME
  FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
   and my_to_date(PARTITION_NAME, 'YYYY_MM_DD') < SYSDATE;
```

You could also force the steps to happen in the order you want-- selecting all the partition names into a collection, for example, and then iterating through the collection to eliminate the partitions for future dates.  Or, since the partition names strings would sort the same way that the date values would sort (assuming MM and DD include leading 0's), you could do an explicit string comparison.

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME
  FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
   and PARTITION_NAME < to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY_MM_DD');
```